# c# template member functions

Tags: c#, generics

How can I define a template member function in C#
For instance I will fill any collection which supports an Add(...) member function, please check out the sample code below

```
public class CInternalCollection
{
    public static void ExternalCollectionTryOne<T<int>>(ref T<int> ext_col, int para_selection = 0)
    {
        foreach (int int_value in m_int_col)
        {
            if (int_value > para_selection)
                ext_col.Add(int_value);
        }
    }

    public static void ExternalCollectionTryTwo<T>(ref T ext_col, int para_selection = 0)
    {
        foreach (int int_value in m_int_col)
        {
            if (int_value > para_selection)
                ext_col.Add(int_value);
        }
    }


    static int[] m_int_col = { 0, -1, -3, 5, 7, -8 };
}
```

The ExternalCollectionTryOne<...>(...) would be the preferred kind, because the int type can be explicit defined, but results in an error:

```
Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The ExternalCollectionTryTwo<...>(...) results in an error:

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)...
```

I hope the problem is clear – any suggestions?

----------------------------- edit --------------------------

The answers with the interface ICollection<..> without a template member works fine and thanks all for this hint,
but I still cannot define successfully a member template(generic) function

So a more simpler example ... how can I define this

```
public class CAddCollectionValues
{
    public static void AddInt<T>(ref T number, int selection)
    {
        T new_T = new T();  //this line is just an easy demonstration to get a compile error with type T  

        foreach (int i_value in m_int_col)
        {
            if (i_value > selection)
                number += i_value; //again the type T cannot be used
        }
    }

    static int[] m_int_col = { 0, -1, -3, 5, 7, -8 };
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing this parameter using `ref`, as you are not mutating the variable.

Comment: `T<int>`?  That's ... huh?  Wat.

Comment: For your edit, look into *generic constraints*. For `new_T`, you'll want the `new()` constraint. For `+= i_value`, you could do something like change that line to `number.Increment(i_value)`, then constraint `T` to implement an interface with an `void Increment(int num)` method on it

Comment: the caller should be able to write

Comment: f.i. the caller should be able to write `CAddCollectionValues.AddInt<int>(int_var, 0)` and `CAddCollectionValues.AddInt<long>(long_var, 0)` the type depends on the caller

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what you want to achieve it would be easier to help you. Now it just looks like you want to use generics in an unnatural way with no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could constrain it to `ICollection<T>`.

```
public static void ExternalCollectionTryTwo<T>(ICollection<T> ext_col, int para_selection = 0)
{
    foreach (int int_value in m_int_col)
    {
        if (int_value > para_selection)
            ext_col.Add(int_value);
    }
}
```

But again, you are only adding `int`s.

This should be fine for you:

```
public static void ExternalCollectionTryTwo(ICollection<int> ext_col, int para_selection = 0)
{
    foreach (int int_value in m_int_col)
    {
        if (int_value > para_selection)
        ext_col.Add(int_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer - the major idea is to avoid the member function using the interface ICollection<..>
which works fine in this example but please consider my edit

Answer (score 0):

Answer about the generic type given, if I well understood, you wish to have a collection of other things than integers so here is the option :

```
public class CInternalCollection<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T[] m_T_col;

    private CInternalCollection() { }

    public CInternalCollection(T[] m_T_col)
    {
        this.m_T_col = m_T_col;
    }

    public void ExternalCollection(ICollection<T> ext_col, T para_selection)
    {
        foreach (T value in m_T_col)
        {
            if (value.CompareTo(para_selection) > 0)
                ext_col.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

### Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] m_int_col = {0,1,2};
        CInternalCollection<int> myCol = new CInternalCollection<int>(m_int_col);
        ICollection<int> ext_int_col = new List<int>();
        ext_int_col.Add(-1);
        ext_int_col.Add(3);
        ext_int_col.Add(2);
        ext_int_col.Add(5);
        myCol.ExternalCollection(ext_int_col, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer - the major idea is to avoid the member function using the interface ICollection<..>
which works fine in this example but please consider my edit

Comment: Your first constraint will be to have a Comparable attribute, this is why I put `where T : IComparable` to be able to use `CompareTo(para_selection)`.